# How do I execute a newly installed application with Sudo?

Tags: linux, ssh, sudo

I have just installed an application on my Amazon EC2 instance called sshpass.  I am having trouble getting it to work properly ( although, it works correctly on a non AWS instance ).  I've read in some forums that I may need to run it as the root user for it to work properly.

On an AWS instance, I must run applications with sudo to run them as the root user. When I try to execute sshpass with `sudo sshpass` bash outputs 'command not found.'

Where & how do I configure sudo so that I can run sshpass as root using sudo?

Answer (score 2):

Give the full path to the command.

E.g.:

```
sudo /opt/local/bin/sshpass
```

Obviously this isn't intended to be an accurate guess as to where you may have put it.

Answer (score 2):

If bash prints "sudo: command not found" then sudo is simply not installed in your system. You may use `su -c sshpass` instead of sudo.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of image (Amazon Linux, Ubuntu, Suse, CentOS, Debian, etc...) you could find out the path where the files are installed, and run them, I assume the reason for this is the fact that the application is in /sbin or /usr/sbin and not in the default path of the non-root user.

To find the location of the files in RPM based distributions (such as, RedHat, Fedora, Amazon Linux, Suse and CentOS):

```
rpm -ql <your package name>
```

For Deb based distributions (Ubuntu, Debian) use:

```
dpkg -L <your package name>
```

In the listing you should be able to see the binaries in a path ending in bin or sbin.